# Shiny app using Reticulate not deploying to shiny.io because of error: utils::tar(... : storing paths of more than 100 bytes is not portable

Tags: shiny, shinyapps, reticulate, sentence-transformers, semantic-search

I am trying to deploy a Shiny app that is using Reticulate to access a huggingface SentenceTransformers model to undertake a semantic search. I can get the app running locally, however, when trying to deploy it to shiny.io I get the following error:

```
Downloaded 360 bytes...Error in uploadCloudBundle(client, application$application_id, bundlePath) : 
  Could not upload file.
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In utils::tar(bundlePath, files = NULL, compression = "gzip",  ... :
  storing paths of more than 100 bytes is not portable:
  ‘./my_env/Lib/site-packages/huggingface_hub/inference/_generated/__pycache__/_async_client.cpython-311.pyc’
2: In utils::tar(bundlePath, files = NULL, compression = "gzip",  ... :
  storing paths of more than 100 bytes is not portable:
  ‘./my_env/Lib/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/__pycache__/_posix_reduction.cpython-311.pyc’
```

I have pasted only the first two warnings here, but there are 50+ as the error message says! Is there a workaround for this?

I am running the app using deployApp()

I have tried using the following lines of code but it hasn't helped:

```
options(rsconnect.max.bundle.files = 3000000)
configureApp("SemanticSearchApp", size="xxlarge")
```

I want my shiny app to be deployed onto shiny.io

**I am new to using stackoverflow and asking for help here. If I haven't done something right please let me know and I will update my post. **

Comment: Update - I managed to fix it by creating a new virtual environment from scratch and only installing the bare minimum of packages needed for my app.